# Match part of Url pattern with or withour trailing slash

Tags: c#, regex

I have to match a pattern with the URL.
I want the pattern to match the domain, and don't care about if it ends in a trailing slash or if it has querystring params, or any subdomains
I want only to accept the protocols http or https.

Here is what I tried:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string>  inputs = new List<string>{
            "https://dotnetfiddle.net/UA6bCb"
        ,"http://www.test.ch/de-ch/apps/weve?anlassId=236601"
        ,"https://www.test.ch/de-ch/apps/weve?anlassId=236601"
        ,"http://test.ch/de-ch/apps/weve?anlassId=236601"
        ,"https://test.ch/de-ch/apps/weve?anlassId=236601"
                ,"https://test.chn/de-ch/apps/weve?anlassId=236601"
                ,"https://www.test.chn/de-ch/apps/weve?anlassId=236601"
                ,"https://test.ch/de-ch/"
                ,"https://test.ch/de-ch"
                ,"https://test.ch/"
                ,"https://test.ch"
                ,"https:test.ch"
        };
    
        Test(inputs);
        
    }

    public static void Test(List<string> inputs)
    {
        var regexString=  @"http(s)?://?([\w-]+\.)?test.ch(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?";
        foreach(var input in inputs){
        var matches = Regex.Match(input,regexString, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            
            if(matches.Success){
                Console.WriteLine("{0} matches {1}", input, regexString);
            }
            else{
                    Console.WriteLine("NO MATCH for {0}", input);
            }
        
        
        }
    }
}
```

This returns

```
NO MATCH: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UA6bCb
Match: http://www.test.ch/de-ch/apps/weve?anlassId=236601
Match: https://www.test.ch/de-ch/apps/weve?anlassId=236601
Match: http://test.ch/de-ch/apps/weve?anlassId=236601
Match: https://test.ch/de-ch/apps/weve?anlassId=236601
Match: https://test.chn/de-ch/apps/weve?anlassId=236601
Match: https://www.test.chn/de-ch/apps/weve?anlassId=236601
Match: https://test.ch/de-ch/
Match: https://test.ch/de-ch
Match: https://test.ch/
Match: https://test.ch
NO MATCH: https:test.ch
```

The problem is that this solution matches *https://test.**chn**/de-ch/apps/weve?anlassId=236601* and *https://www.test.**chn**/de-ch/apps/weve?anlassId=236601*

This should be false because the domain ends in chn.

I haven't been able to get the right regex.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use anchors. See https://regex101.com/r/PrYANW/1

Comment: var regexString=  @"http(s)?://?([\w-]+\.)?test.ch/([\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?";

Comment: @azuremycry Thank you, but this won't work either, because this causes https://test.ch not to match but as stated I need it to be able to be with or without trailing slash

Comment: You don't need a Regex. You can pass the entire url to the `UriBuilder` class and then get back the `Host` property. It gives you back the domain name without the trailing slash nor any protocol (`http://`) in front of it. Note it keeps instead the `www.`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew did you even read the question? This is far from a duplicate, I'm not trying to match an entire string

Comment: You are not trying, you *are* matching entire strings that are URLs. If you need a morespecific answer, please precise the question. And your regex already [matches](https://regex101.com/r/PrYANW/2) URLs with and without trailing slash.

Comment: @Krusty. No. This is just a code to demonstrate the case.I have a configuration file on a system where I can configure some url patterns allowed to access the system. So I'm searching for a regex.. not for c# code

Comment: Other than adding anchors, you may further enhance the regex to `^https?://([^/]+\.)?test\.ch(/.*)?$`. See https://ideone.com/2gnN6o. No match for `chn` domain, as you need.

Comment: Answer for your question is: var regexString=  @"http(s)?://?([\w-]+\.)?test.ch(/|$)([\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?";

Comment: @azuremycry Thank you. Sad I can't mark an answer, because my question was closed (false-duplicate)

Comment: but just tell me if my solution works for you :)?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to exclude `test.chn` then you can use a negative lookbehind to ensure `ch` is not followed by `n`:

```
"http(s)?://?([\w-]+\.)?test.ch(?!n)(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?"
```

I added the part `(?!n)`.